# how to extracting Strings from List, before storing in Firebase? Flutter

Tags: flutter, list

I've a parent screen 'EditProfieScreen" and a child screen.
After picked some items from the child screen, they are reflected in the parent screen using the 'callback' function as a list. The original list was structured with 'id', 'name', 'isSelected'. Now, I'm trying to extract the list of name and store them in Firebase but not sure how to do it.

Here is the list structure:

```
class Skills {
final int id;
final String name;
bool isSelected;

Skills({
required this.id,
required this.name,
required this.isSelected,
});

Map\<String, dynamic\> toMap() {
return {
'id': id,
'name': name,
'isSelected': isSelected,
};
}

factory Skills.fromMap(Map\<String, dynamic\> map) {
return Skills(
id: map\['id'\] ?? '',
name: map\['name'\] ?? '',
isSelected: map\['isSelected'\] ?? '',
);
}
}

//Data
final allItems = \<Skills\>\[
Skills(id: 1, name: 'Flutter', isSelected: false),
Skills(id: 2, name: 'SwiftUI', isSelected: false),
Skills(id: 3, name: 'Kotlin', isSelected: false),
Skills(id: 4, name: 'JavaScript', isSelected: false),
```

Below is the part on the parent screen 'EditProfileScreen'. pickedItem is the list that was picked from the child screen.

```
class EditProfileScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-profile-screen';

  const EditProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<EditProfileScreen> createState() => _EditProfileScreenState();
}

class _EditProfileScreenState extends ConsumerState<EditProfileScreen> {
  
  List<Skills> skills = allItems;
  List pickedItemsFromChips = [];
  bool isPickedItem = false;


  //Callback for PickedItems selected from ChipPopUpScreen
  void callback(List pickedItems) {
    setState(() {
      pickedItemsFromChips = pickedItems;
      isPickedItem = true;
    });
  }

  //Getting the list of pickedItemsFromChips in Strings 
  

  //Storing User Data to Firebase 
  void storeUserData() async {
    List<String> skills = [];
    
    if (name.isNotEmpty) {
      ref.read(authControllerProvider).saveUserDataToFirebase(
          context, skills);
    }
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text('Edit Profile'),

          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: storeUserData, icon: const Icon(Icons.done)),
            ),
          ]),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [

            //Skills Chips Selection
            InkWell(
              child: isPickedItem
                  ? Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Wrap(
                            children: [
                              ...List.generate(
                                pickedItemsFromChips.length,
                                (index) => Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${pickedItemsFromChips[index].name}, ',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'Choose the Skills you have',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
              onTap: () => showChildScreen
            ),
```

I tried using the following but was warned that 'A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.

```
final List<String> pickedItemsFromChipsNames = pickedItemsFromChips.map((skills) => skills.name).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you call "callback()"?. Otherwise the "pickedItemsFromChips" list is empty so you can't map it.

Comment: the callback is from a child screen, with the following codes. pickedItem should adopted the same class structure as the class Skills.  


TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //Save data to EditProfileScreen

                        widget.callback(pickedItems);

                        Navigator.pop(context); //Dismiss the popup screen
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Done',
                      ),

Comment: Try this: final List<String> pickedItemsFromChipsNames = List<String>.from(pickedItemsFromChips.map((skills) => skills.name));

Comment: Hi Hoang Phuc, I tried but still got errors. 
I'm using Riverpod for this project. Do you think if I can use riverpod provider to manage the state change between child and parent screen for this issue?

Comment: Hi, I think all methods lead to correct results. Did you get the same error? Can you post the error details?

Comment: error: A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<String>'.